# Reading registrys from binary file

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

The program after writing in a binary file registrys that contain:

```
StringBuilder name0 = new StringBuilder(15);
int stock0, safe0;
double cost0;
```

has to read the data of one registry by giving the id based on the position of the registry.

So because the registry is 20 bytes, the pos of each registry will be:

```
pos = (id-1) * 20;
```

right?

The problem is that the `StringBuilder` doesn't hold exactly 15 characters but the length of the name you write each time and instead of reading the data you need, you read garbage. Isn't there a way to declare a string that will always have an exact size, so to read the data correctly?

Code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give file name: ");
    string f = Console.ReadLine();

    StringBuilder name0 = new StringBuilder(15);
    bool criterion = true;
    int stock0, safe0;
    double cost0;
    long id, pos;

    try
    {
        FileStream fs = File.Open(f, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);

        while (criterion != false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Give name (10 char) or STOP for end");
            name0.Insert(0, Console.ReadLine());

            if ((name0.ToString()).Equals("STOP"))
                criterion = false;
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Stock : ");
                stock0 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Safe: ");
                safe0 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Cost: ");
                cost0 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                writer.Write(name0.ToString());
                writer.Write(stock0);
                writer.Write(safe0);
                writer.Write(cost0);
            } // else

            name0.Remove(0, name0.Length);

        } //while

        Console.WriteLine(" Give ID: ");
        id = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        pos = (id - 1) * 20; //20 = megethos eggrafis(2 int+ 1db + 16chars)

        if ((pos < fs.Length) && (id != 0))
        {
            fs.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            name0.Insert(0, reader.ReadChars(name0.Length));
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", name0);
            stock0 = reader.ReadInt32();
            Console.WriteLine("\nStock: {0}", stock0);
            safe0 = reader.ReadInt32();
            Console.WriteLine("\nSafe: {0}", safe0);
            cost0 = reader.ReadDouble();
            Console.WriteLine("\nCost: {0}", cost0);
            name0.Length = 0;
        }

        fs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is almost impossible to understand. Why don't you describe what you are trying to acheive rather than how you are trying to acheive it? We might be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: I don't see any way to get 20 bytes out of that

Comment: I counted the length of each variable, 8 bytes(2 integers) + 8 bytes(1 double) + 4 bytes(16 chars) = 20 bytes? How can i get the position of each record? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: umm, 4 bytes for 16 characters? what charset is that?

Comment: The unicode chars are 2 bytes each not 2 bits(my bad!). I have a terrible book from my university that says Unicode chars are 2 bits...

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a fixed-length string in C#, unless you declare it as a `char[15]`. But you can pad the value with spaces manually on writing and trim spaces on reading:

```
// writing
writer.Write(name0.ToString().PadRight(15));

//reading
name0.Insert(0, reader.ReadChars(15));
name0 = new StringBuilder(name0.ToString().Trim());
```

Comment: that's nice but the string builder doesn't have the method Trim() :-/

Comment: I've fixed the code now. I'm not sure whether it's good to use `StringBuilder` in this context, unless you're really concerned about performance.

Comment: Ok, the name is read correctly if instead of reader.ReadChars(name0.Length) you write reader.ReadChars(name0.capacity)(though the first character is something weird like *) but all the other values are wrong. Am i doing something wrong in reading integers from binary file?

Comment: in fact, you should've done `reader.ReadChars(15)` instead of `capacity` or `length`.

As for the weird data at the beginning - maybe it's the UTF file header?